# Maven: Project A not respecting Project B's exclusion

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have two projects A, and B.

Project A depends on Project B. Project B depends on a library C which depends on a library D.
I own both A and B but they live in separate code bases and are independent. Project B is like an internal common helper library.

```
- A 
-- B 
--- C (version 1.1)
---- D (version 1.1)
```

I want to upgrade D to a newer minor version, let's say 1.5.

So in B's pom.xml file, I imported D (v1.5) directly. Then excluded D from C. Example:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>D</groupId>
  <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>C</groupId>
  <artifactId>fizzbuzz</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>D</groupId>
        <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Next if I run

```
[~/projectB] $ mvn dependency:tree
```

I confirm that only 1.5 is used, not 1.1. Next I build a new local snapshot of B. And specify Project A to use that one.

My problem is when I build Project A, it continues to use v1.1 and ignores the exclusion in B.
This always returns 1.1 instead of the 1.5 that I want.

```
[~/projectA] $ mvn dependency:tree
```

Project A never imports C or D directly, it only get library D from importing Project B.

I've tried:

- Reloading the maven imports
- Running mvn clean install numerous times.
- Deleting the folders from my .m2/ directory to force reimports

I'm out of troubleshooting ideas. Does anyone else have any tips?

Comment: This sounds strange. Show us the full POMs

Comment: Does A or one of its parent POMs contains a `<dependencyManagement>` with D in it?